# Using Javascript with Brackets in Field Name

Tags: javascript, dom, brackets

How do I reference a HTML form element whose name contains brackets?

For example,

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="myElement[7]" />
</form>
```

I do not have the option of renaming the form element and I cannot use jquery.

How would I access this element using javascript alone? I already tried using:

```
alert(document.myForm.myElement\\[7\\].type);
```

The result is "undefined". I also tried the above javascript snipped without the slashes and also got "undefined".

What is the correct syntax for javascript to access a field named with brackets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```
alert( document.myForm.elements['myElement[7]'].type );
```

Comment: This did fix the original error, but now I get "missing ) after argument list" in Firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: It's probably related to a different part of the JavaScript code.